# Take the 1000th ms data in a window of 1 second

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I want to take the 1000th ms data in a window of 1 second, need help on the windowing function. Basically i need to Aggregate the data to second level i.e. take the 1000th ms data in a window of 1 second (by using Window / Rank / Partition function)

Below is the code i'm trying..

```
val result3DF = spark.sql("select a.* from (select p.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY xxx_ts order by stime DESC) as RN from global_temp.CAN_Table p)a where RN=1")

where xxx_ts is of type yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss and stime is in epoch(ex:1526630451865) which is in milliseconds level.
```

Comment: Please add some sample data, and expected results, so we can help..